# All static files result in 404 error in laravel on server run

Tags: php, laravel

When I host my website on the live server with cpanel then the website is working perfectly but when I host the site on my local host then it gives so many problem.

[image: No any css files and images are not loading]

I am trying to solve this from last 10 hours and totally onto it still can't find the solution please help me :(  :(

It gives this error =

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
img2.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Please give me the solution : (

Comment: Usually I will take a look at the access log to know who returns 404.

Comment: Using blade? Post html code to show how load images, pls

Comment: If using npm, .. tried `npm run dev`  via CLI ?

Comment: @shingo it has this error please look at the screenshot = https://prnt.sc/oDU7F1aHJJPC

in server it works fine but in local host the local path is not acceesible what can I do for that?

Comment: @Alessandro it has this error please look at the screenshot = prnt.sc/oDU7F1aHJJPC in server it works fine but in local host the local path is not acceesible what can I do for that?

Comment: Can I see how you refer to these images in your code?

Comment: @DinushChathurya Here is few screenshot please look at this 

1 - https://prnt.sc/2m0rmYhuHQcv
2 - https://prnt.sc/3fqvjQ-F0yaz
3 - https://prnt.sc/3L8z2F80Hgqy
4 - https://prnt.sc/eZ_nh0Fb5Or-

When I change the path from /public/assest to /assests then it works perfectly, how can I changet that with route or something else? : (

Comment: {{ asset("landing/css/responsive.css") }} use this approach in href section

Comment: @DinushChathurya there are hundred of lines of codes... I cannot change in all... can we do some setup on the cofig files ? so it applies for all ?

Comment: Look like a config issue, you've configured the public directory as the root of your site for a specific domain, so the site works on the server. I guess if you set the address of that domain to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file, the site on your local matchine will work too.

Comment: @ArjunGhimire please post your local web server configuration (are you using nginx or apache on localhost)? You have to point web root to `/public` folder

Comment: Hello everyone I found the solution, Actually it was because I run it outside of apache localhost thats why it was giving those errors, when I run it through the htdocs folder from apache then its working perfectly : ) thanks everyone : )

Comment: @ArjunGhimire glad you solved it  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello everyone I found the solution, Actually it was because I run it outside of apache localhost thats why it was giving those errors, when I run it through the htdocs folder from apache then its working perfectly : ) thanks everyone : )